# Sign in with google using firebase

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication

I am working on a react app that lets a user sign in with user. I am using Firebase to handle authentication. I am using express to write cloud functions. I want to set up signing in with Google but I have a couple of questions.

Here is what I have so far on the backend of the route to sign in with Google:

```
const { id_token } = req.body //de-structure id token passed in through body of request

const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
```

How do I register this user using these credentials into my database? How do I check if this user is already registered? I want to be able to save data for this user so every time he/she logs in with google, his/her data is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import firebase admin in your application.

Admin SDK allows to interact with firebase from the privileged environment to perform actions like:

1. Read and write Realtime Database data with full admin privileges
2. Generate and verify firebase based auth tokens
3. Access Google Cloud Platform resources like Cloud Storage buckets and Cloud Firestore  databases associated with your Firebase projects

I hope this helps.